# TSQL - How to search a string in multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am unsure how to get SQL to do what I am trying to figure out.  I have one student, and depending on their grade level, would be in one of three schools (schoolid).

I need to return only the StudentID and SchoolID of the school the student is currently in, based on the grade level.  How do I search in this way please?

[image]

Desired Result (the student is in grade 12, therefore the SchoolID is 500):

[image]

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/caa7d/2/0)

Thank you.

Comment: This design is absolutely awful. It is horribly denormalized and violates normalization at nearly every step of the way. The students current grade should be kept in the student record and nowhere else. You are violating 1NF by having multiple data points in a single column with the grades offered.

Comment: I agree and this was not my design and I am not in a department that would change it.  This was taken from a view with data combined from multiple places.  Probably not the best example, but it's what I have to work with.  We do have to keep track of which grades are offered at each schoolID.  Some schools don't have grades 01,02 for example, and others have 01 thru 05.

Comment: The student's current grade is kept in the student's record in a normalized table and in other views.  It's just this particular view I'm working on has all the grades the school offers in one column.

Comment: Ahh a view...that explains that part at least. Probably also explains the delimited mess of grades offered. Any chance you can just hit the base tables instead of using this view? It would make your life a lot easier. When searching delimited data you either have to parse it back into rows or do a nonSARGable wildcard LIKE search.

Comment: Then look in the view and see is the data is properly normalized some where

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `GradesOfferedInSchool` never overlap for a given student, e.g. Aether High covers grades 6 through 12 and Fizz Buzz Academy covers 4 through 7 for Alayne McVowel?

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange.  I had never heard of 'Sargable' before so I looked it up on this link and it helped: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/  .  I will look into using base tables for that moving forward.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where GradesOfferedInSchool like '%' + cast(StudentCurrentGrade as varchar(max)) + '%'
```

But that is a terrible data design
Should not have multiple values in one column

This is still just a hack as this would find '12b'

If this is a view then look for normalized data
better but still a hack

```
 where GradesOfferedInSchool like '% ' + cast(StudentCurrentGrade as varchar(max)) + ', %'
    or GradesOfferedInSchool like cast(StudentCurrentGrade as varchar(max)) + ', %'
    or GradesOfferedInSchool like '%, ' + cast(StudentCurrentGrade as varchar(max))
    or GradesOfferedInSchool = cast(StudentCurrentGrade as varchar(max))
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/caa7d/13 with this solution (Using CONCAT() instead, but the same idea)

Comment: @Frisbee, I don't disagree, it's an inherited design.  So I understand the logic, you are telling the WHERE clause to look in the GradesOfferedInSchool column for everything in the StudentCurrentGrade column that matches.  Is that how you would say what's happening here?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: '%' is just a wildcard so anywhere in the string

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using Microsoft SQL Server. The `CAST` is needed otherwise it was throwing an error due to the different datatypes of the fields.

```
SELECT
 StudentID,
 SchoolID

FROM dbo.StudentFeederPatterns
WHERE GradesOfferedInSchool LIKE '%' + CAST(StudentCurrentGrade AS VARCHAR) + '%'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/caa7d/19/0)

Answer (score 0):

Weird why you do INT on [StudentCurrentGrade] where 'PK' and 'KK' are the option for it
anyway:

```
SELECT [StudentID]
     , [SchoolID]
     , [GradesOfferedInSchool]
     , [StudentCurrentGrade]
  FROM [dbo].[StudentFeederPatterns]
 WHERE CHARINDEX( CAST([StudentCurrentGrade] AS VARCHAR)
                  , [GradesOfferedInSchool]) > 0
```

Comment: Regarding the INT, grade 12 was the only data given in the sample, but I do see your point.  Thanks.